# Error in installing PHP Symfony framework.

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install Symfony on Windows 8. I am using Appserv as my local server.

Step 1: I opened the the folder C:\AppServ\www. Then I opened the command line (cmd) and entered the following command:

> php -r "file_put_contents('symfony',
>   file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"

This installed a symfony file in the www folder.

Step 2: I then entered the following command but it gave me the error.

> php symfony new symfony_project

This is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

I don't know what to do. Please Help.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer/issues/260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of posting a link, you should post a full response.
These are the instructions:

1. Download this file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it
   somewhere in your computer. for example, c:\AppServ\php\cacert.pem
2. Open your php.ini config file.
3. Look for the following config and
   uncomment it if it exists or add it if it does not:

> ```
> [curl]
> curl.cainfo="c:\AppServ\php\cacert.pem"
> ```

Comment: You are welcome! Glad you got it working - I know how it feels to get a good response and get something working.